How do I form a Postgres SQL to return multiple array objects instead of an array of multiple array objects?
I have multiple tables representing form options, from which I want to request the data as a JSON array of objects containing key-value pairs.
However, I'm struggling to return the data in the correct shape, using the unbuilt Postgres JSON functions.
I tried this:
SELECT json_agg(form_values.data)
   FROM ( SELECT json_build_object('state', json_agg(json_build_object('value', os.id, 'name,', os.name))) as data
           FROM opt_state os
        UNION ALL
         SELECT json_build_object('status', json_agg(json_build_object('value', ostat.id, 'name,', ostat.name))) 
           FROM opt_status ostat
        UNION ALL
         SELECT json_build_object('survey_grade', json_agg(json_build_object('value', osg.id, 'name,', osg.name))) 
           FROM opt_survey_grade osg) form_values;

Which returns this, where each array object is listed as part of a parent array:
[
  {
    "state": [
      {
        "value": 2,
        "name,": "Massachusetts"
      },
      {
        "value": 1,
        "name,": "New York"
      },
      {
        "value": 3,
        "name,": "Vermont"
      }
      etc etc
    ]
  },
  {
    "status": [
      {
        "value": 1,
        "name,": "Open"
      },
      {
        "value": 2,
        "name,": "Closed"
      }
    ]
  },
  etc etc
]

But I want the resulting JSON to look like this:
{
  "state": [
    {
      "value": 2,
      "name,": "Massachusetts"
    },
    {
      "value": 1,
      "name,": "New York"
    },
    {
      "value": 3,
      "name,": "Vermont"
    }
    etc etc
  ],
  "status": [
    {
      "value": 1,
      "name,": "Open"
    },
    {
      "value": 2,
      "name,": "Closed"
    }
  ],
etc etc
}


The probable solution is to use the json_object_agg function instead of json_agg to aggregate the JSON objects directly into a single JSON object:
SELECT json_object_agg(form_values.key, form_values.data) AS result
FROM (
    SELECT 'state' AS key, json_agg(json_build_object('value', os.id, 'name', os.name)) AS data
    FROM opt_state os
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'status' AS key, json_agg(json_build_object('value', ostat.id, 'name', ostat.name)) AS data
    FROM opt_status ostat
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'survey_grade' AS key, json_agg(json_build_object('value', osg.id, 'name', osg.name)) AS data
    FROM opt_survey_grade osg
) form_values;

